# Mobile device-like keyboard on demand using jquery and code injection

Tags: php, jquery

Like when you use a tablet, every time you touch an input text field the browser fires the virtual keyboard.

Im trying to develop the same function but on desktop on webpages outsize of my control (third party web sites like google) but they are loaded using a php gateway so i can insert code on them.

My general idea is to use [this implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/) on jquery:

```
var simulateTyping = "Hello World!!1\b";

$('#keyboard').keyboard({
    // *** choose layout & positioning ***
    // choose from 'qwerty', 'alpha', 'international', 'dvorak', 'num' or
    // 'custom' (to use the customLayout below)
    layout: 'qwerty',
    customLayout: {
        'default': [
            'd e f a u l t',
            '{meta1} {meta2} {accept} {cancel}'
            ],
        'meta1': [
            'm y m e t a 1',
            '{meta1} {meta2} {accept} {cancel}'
            ],
        'meta2': [
            'M Y M E T A 2',
            '{meta1} {meta2} {accept} {cancel}'
            ]
    },
    // Used by jQuery UI position utility
    position: {
        of: null, // null = attach to input/textarea; use $(sel) to attach elsewhere
        my: 'center top',
        at: 'center top',
        at2: 'center bottom' // used when "usePreview" is false
    },

    // true: preview added above keyboard; false: original input/textarea used
    usePreview: true,

    // if true, the keyboard will always be visible
    alwaysOpen: false,

    // if true, keyboard will remain open even if the input loses focus.
    stayOpen: false,

    // *** change keyboard language & look ***
    display: {
        'meta1' : '\u2666', // Diamond
        'meta2' : '\u2665', // Heart
        'a'     : '\u2714:Accept (Shift-Enter)', // check mark (accept)
        'accept': 'Accept:Accept (Shift-Enter)',
        'alt'   : 'AltGr:Alternate Graphemes',
        'b'     : '\u2190:Backspace', // Left arrow (same as &larr;)
        'bksp'  : 'Bksp:Backspace',
        'c'     : '\u2716:Cancel (Esc)', // big X, close/cancel
        'cancel': 'Cancel:Cancel (Esc)',
        'clear' : 'C:Clear', // clear num pad
        'combo' : '\u00f6:Toggle Combo Keys',
        'dec'   : '.:Decimal', // num pad decimal '.' (US) & ',' (EU)
        'e'     : '\u21b5:Enter', // down, then left arrow - enter symbol
        'enter' : 'Enter:Enter',
        'lock'  : '\u21ea Lock:Caps Lock', // caps lock
        's'     : '\u21e7:Shift', // thick hollow up arrow
        'shift' : 'Shift:Shift',
        'sign'  : '\u00b1:Change Sign', // +/- sign for num pad
        'space' : ' :Space',
        't'     : '\u21e5:Tab', // right arrow to bar
        'tab'   : '\u21e5 Tab:Tab' // \u21b9 is the true tab symbol
    },

    // Message added to the key title while hovering, if the mousewheel plugin exists
    wheelMessage: 'Use mousewheel to see other keys',

    css : {
        // input & preview
        input          : 'ui-widget-content ui-corner-all',
        // keyboard container
        container      : 'ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix', 
        // default state
        buttonDefault  : 'ui-state-default ui-corner-all',
        // hovered button
        buttonHover    : 'ui-state-hover',
        // Action keys (e.g. Accept, Cancel, Tab, etc); this replaces
        // "actionClass" option
        buttonAction   : 'ui-state-active',
        // used when disabling the decimal button {dec} when a decimal exists
        // in the input area
        buttonDisabled : 'ui-state-disabled'
        },

    // *** Useability ***
    // Auto-accept content when clicking outside the keyboard (popup will close)
    autoAccept: false,

    // Prevents direct input in the preview window when true
    lockInput: false,

    // Prevent keys not in the displayed keyboard from being typed in
    restrictInput: false,


    acceptValid  : true,


    tabNavigation: false,


    enterNavigation : false,

    enterMod : 'altKey',


    appendLocally: false,

    stickyShift  : true,

    preventPaste: false,


    maxLength: false,


    repeatDelay  : 500,

    repeatRate   : 20,   

    // resets the keyboard to the default keyset when visible
    resetDefault : false,

    // Event (namespaced) on the input to reveal the keyboard.
    // To disable it, just set it to ''.
    openOn: 'focus',

    // Event (namepaced) for when the character is added to the input
    // (clicking on the keyboard)
    keyBinding: 'mousedown',

    // combos (emulate dead keys)
    // if user inputs `a the script converts it to à, ^o becomes ô, etc.
    useCombos: true,
    // if you add a new combo, you may need to update the regex below
    combos: {
// uncomment out the next line, then read the Combos Regex section below
//        '<': { 3: '\u2665' }, // turn <3 into ♥ - change regex below
        'a': { e: "\u00e6" }, // ae ligature
        'A': { E: "\u00c6" },
        'o': { e: "\u0153" }, // oe ligature
        'O': { E: "\u0152" }
    },


    initialized : function(e, keyboard, el) {},
    visible     : function(e, keyboard, el) {},
    change      : function(e, keyboard, el) {},
    beforeClose : function(e, keyboard, el, accepted) {},
    accepted    : function(e, keyboard, el) {},
    canceled    : function(e, keyboard, el) {},
    hidden      : function(e, keyboard, el) {},


    switchInput : function(keyboard, goToNext, isAccepted) {},


    validate    : function(keyboard, value, isClosing) { return true; }

}) 
    // activate the typing extension
    .addTyping();


$('#keyboard').getkeyboard().regex = /([`\'~\^\"ao])([a-z])/mig;

// Typing Extension
$('#icon').click(function() {
    var kb = $('#keyboard').getkeyboard();
    kb.reveal().typeIn(simulateTyping, 500, function() {
        // do something after text is added
        // kb.accept();
    });
});
```

To make that work i need to wrap the text field using:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <input id="keyboard" type="text">
    <img id="icon" src="http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/demo/keyboard.png">
</div>
```

So in theory i need to insert an id and a wrap div to each input and textfield of the site, but im very confuse of how to do this and how to re utilize the jquery code to make it work in all the site's inputs.

By the way, im using [this](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard) jquery lib. Also, and I dont want to be off topic, but if you think i can solve this using an already executable program on Windows that runs on backgroud and fires when an input is in focus and goes when it lose the focus will be also an acceptable answer.

**EDIT: im using an in app browser, is an extension of the AIR development platform. So im loading web pages inside my app using webkit for a Kiosk application**

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about developing either a browser extension, or a UserScript/Greasemonkey Script to wrap all the input elements? The JS code involved should be quite simple, I doubt it would even justify using jQuery.

This solution would only be appropriate if you control the client browsers, obviously anyone who wants your keyboard functionality would need the extension/script installed.

Comment: This is not the way to go, because im using an in app browser, is an extension of the AIR development platform. So im loading web pages inside my app using webkit for a Kiosk application.

Comment: Ok, you should probably state that in the question